# Как сделать чтобы на последнем постере слайдер останавливался и не двигался дальше?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

кто может подсказать как сделать чтобы слайдер больше не двигался после достижения последней фотки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');

const movies = [
  'assets/img/horimiya poster.jpg',
  'assets/img/Magichbattle.jpg',
  'assets/img/Lamborgini.jpg',
  'assets/img/bFG5NYfODoVevfIE__daef5ba680f448333805d8445444b400.jpg',
  'assets/img/aULWvyGBYqsKGiaN1qfrSKlzPHE.jpg',
  'assets/img/97045.jpg',
  'assets/img/661375314418.jpg',
  'assets/img/img_1563455630_1372_627_it_ends.jpg',
  // Добавить больше фильмов по мере необходимости
];

let currentIndex = 0;

function updateSlider() {
  slider.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    const moviePoster = document.createElement('img');
    moviePoster.src = movies[i];
    moviePoster.alt = `Movie Poster ${ i + 1}`;
    moviePoster.classList.add('movie-poster');
    slider.appendChild(moviePoster);
  }

  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${-currentIndex * 220}px)`; // 220px - ширина слайда
}

updateSlider();

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1;
    updateSlider();
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex < movies.length - 1) {
    currentIndex += 1;
    updateSlider();
  } else {
    // Если текущий индекс равен последнему постеру, отключите обработчик события для кнопки "Вперед"
    nextButton.removeEventListener('click', nextButtonClickHandler);
  }
});

function nextButtonClickHandler() {
  if (currentIndex < movies.length - 1) {
    currentIndex += 1;
    updateSlider();
  }
}

// Добавляем обработчик события для кнопки "Вперед" в начале
nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextButtonClickHandler);
```

```css
.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Добавьте это свойство для скрытия скрытых постеров */
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.movie-poster {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.prev-button,
.next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}

.next-button {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <!-- Здесь будут отображаться постеры фильмов -->
  </div>
  <button class="prev-button">Предыдущий</button>
  <button class="next-button">Следующий</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Храни гдето значение, на каком именно ты сейча находишься слайде, если это значение > movies.length после нажатия кнопки следуйщий. Возвращай return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на скорую руку, то так, хотя в интернете есть и более продуманные примеры и даже готовые библиотеки.

В вашей реализации одна из ошибок - это вот это вот:

```
if (currentIndex < movies.length - 1) {
```

Текущий индекс всегда будет меньше общего количества слайдов, т.к. слайды отображаются по 3. Можно грубо указать, что `(currentIndex < movies.length - 4)`  или немного сложнее как в примере ниже с учетом возможной адаптивности. Но это не идеальное решение.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');

const movies = [
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/6raORdA.jpeg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/EXB5luW.jpeg',
  // Добавить больше фильмов по мере необходимости
];

let currentIndex = 0;
const maxTranslate = (movies.length)*220 - document.querySelector('.slider-container').clientWidth - 20;

function updateSlider() {
  slider.innerHTML = '';
  if (slider.innerHTML === '') {
    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
      const moviePoster = document.createElement('img');
      moviePoster.src = movies[i];
      moviePoster.alt = `Movie Poster ${ i + 1}`;
      moviePoster.classList.add('movie-poster');
      slider.appendChild(moviePoster);
    }
  }

  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${-currentIndex * 220}px)`; // 220px - ширина слайда
}

updateSlider();

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1;
    updateSlider();
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextButtonClickHandler);

function nextButtonClickHandler() {
   //if (currentIndex > movies.length - 4) return;
   if ( currentIndex * 220 >= maxTranslate) return;
   currentIndex += 1;
   updateSlider();
   console.log(maxIndex, currentIndex ) 
}

// Добавляем обработчик события для кнопки "Вперед" в начале
nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextButtonClickHandler);
```

```css
.slider-container {
  /*width: 80%;*/
  width: 640px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Добавьте это свойство для скрытия скрытых постеров */
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.movie-poster {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.prev-button,
.next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}

.next-button {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <!-- Здесь будут отображаться постеры фильмов -->
  </div>
  <button class="prev-button">Предыдущий</button>
  <button class="next-button">Следующий</button>
</div>
```